# jQuery - stopping anchor <a> from redirecting using onClick="function(this)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

this is my anchor i am using in CodeIgnitor pagination.

```
<a href="http://perfex_crm.ng/clients/get_front_page_jobs/2" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-ci-pagination-page="2">2</a>
```

now this is the definition of function in Javascript

```
function myFunction(e){
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

Now e is an anchor  which is shown in the console. but when i try

```
e.preventDefault()
```

it gives me this error.

```
e.preventDefault is not a function
```

and obviously page redirected which is original problem i want to solve. i do not want it to redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the value of `this` which is the `<a>` element object, not the event object.

You could pass `event` instead, but you really should avoid using intrinsic event attributes (which have a bunch of gotchas) and switch to `addEventListener`.

```
const links = document.querySelector('[data-ci-pagination-page]');
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener(myFunction); 
}
```

Comment: sir for time being my code works but for future reference i will use your advice. now i am using this code. how can i pass 2 parameters? 


`code`
    function myFunction(e , a){

    console.log(e);

    e.preventDefault();

    var pageno = $(a).attr('data-ci-pagination-page');
    }

Answer (score 2):

Since you've written `onclick="myFunction(this)"` you pass `this` as an argument, where `this` is your `<a>` element.

Try passing the `event` instead: `onclick="myFunction(event)"`

Comment: @xkrlaix, happy to help. Also I'd recommend you to follow Quentin's advice.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work like a charm:

```js
function myFunction(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="http://perfex_crm.ng/clients/get_front_page_jobs/2" onclick="myFunction(event)" data-ci-pagination-page="2">2</a>
```